# Hide a div on load with jquery if radio is not selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three radio buttons, on load one of them might be selected.  If the value of 2 is selected i need to show a div, if the other two are the div should hide.

The click function is working fine but if when the page loads it still shows the div even if the radio isn't selected

```
$("input[name='AssignmentType']").click(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == 2) {
            $('#selection').show();
        } else {
            $('#selection').hide(); /* If you want to be hidden if it's not */
        }
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-10">
            <div>
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field AssignmentType must be a number." htmlattributes="{ checked = True, class = form-control, id = AllCodes }" id="AssignmentType" name="AssignmentType" type="radio" value="0">
                Available for All Employees
            </div>
            <div>
<input htmlattributes="{ checked = True, class = form-control, id = EEClass }" id="AssignmentType" name="AssignmentType" type="radio" value="1">
                Available only to Employees in Class
            </div>
            <div>
 <input htmlattributes="{ checked = True, class = form-control, id = EECombo }" id="AssignmentType" name="AssignmentType" type="radio" value="2">
                Available for All Employees in combination of below Department, Position, State
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hey, please don't compose [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148185/show-css-hidden-div-on-load-using-jquery#32148185), edit them instead of deleting and asking a new question.

Comment: I don't know what that means

Comment: You should give some html with your jQuery, can you show some more?

Answer (score 1):

You should move all of your code out to a separate function then call that during the click and when the document loads.

```
function hideSelection(type) {
    if ($(type).val() == 2) {
        $('#selection').show();
    } else {
        $('#selection').hide(); /* If you want to be hidden if it's not */
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
     hideSelection("input[name='AssignmentType']");
     $("input[name='AssignmentType']").click(function () {hideSelection("input[name='AssignmentType']");});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how your HTML structure is, but you can make this with CSS in case your structure is set up in a way that you can use the tilde selector

```css
div.onlyif {
    display: none;
}
input[name="AssignmentType"][value="2"]:checked ~ div.onlyif {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p>Select something:</p>
    1: <input type="radio" name="AssignmentType" value="1"> <br/>
    2: <input type="radio" name="AssignmentType" value="2"> <br/>
    3: <input type="radio" name="AssignmentType" value="3"> <br/>
    <div class="onlyif">Looks like you selected #2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it this way.

My script was

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var chk = $('.selectedRadio input:radio:checked');
        var val = chk.attr('value');            
        if (val == 2) {
            $('#selection').show();
        } else {
            $('#selection').hide(); /* If you want to be hidden if it's not */
        }
    });
```

I then added `class="selectedRadio"` to each button.  I was then able to grab the value out of the button that was checked and show or hide the `#selection` div

I then had my click function below it to run when I made selections

```
$("input[name='AssignmentType']").click(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 2) {
        $('#selection').show();
    } else {
        $('#selection').hide(); /* If you want to be hidden if it's not */
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ($(input[name='AssignmentType'] ).val() == 2) {
            $('#selection').show();
        } else {
            $('#selection').hide(); 
        }
});
```

Comment: This only works on page load, not on click and will be redundant if they want to perform the same task twice.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">I am here</div>
    <input type="button" value="Click Me!" onclick="document.getElementById('div1').style.visibility='hidden';" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The click works just fine. It's when the page loads that doesnt.  The div doesn't hide depending on the selection